# Python. Множества

Tags: python, множества

Сделал программу, всё работает, но если 1 задание - ещё нормально выводит, то 2 - нет, ибо нужно что бы цифры были в порядке возрастания. Возможно я неправильно обращаюсь с числовыми множествами.

Задание: есть множество целых чисел {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}
1)Сделать функцию, которая будет считать количество уникальных цифр в числе n.
2)Выводит в порядке возрастания все цифры, которых нету в числе n

Мой код:

```
n = input("Число: ")
a = {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"}

result=list(set(a) & set(n))
print(len(result))

result1=list(set(a)-set(result))
print(result1)
```

Comment: Используйте sorted(result)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

если я правильно понял задачу то так:

```
num = input()

task1 = len(set(num))

task2 = sorted(set('0123456789') - set(num))

print(task1)
print(*task2)
```